# React Javascript, find in a array undefined and skip it

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, undefined

I have an array of objects

```
const contentTypes = [
    {
        "contentType": {
            "content_type_id": 2,
            "content_type": "image",
        },
    },
    {
        "contentType": {
            "content_type_id": 3,
            "content_type": "video",
        },
    },
    {
        "contentType": {
            "content_type_id": 1,
            "content_type": "audio",
        },
    },
]
```

This is my function `setType`, where I find any element and set the `content_type_id` to `content_type`. I convert the value in a string

```
const setType = (selectedType) => {
    _setType(selectedType)
    const typeString = contentTypes.find((item) => {
        return item.contentType.content_type_id === selectedType
    }).contentType.content_type;
    onTypeChange(typeString)
}
```

My problem is that I also have an element in the array `contentTypes` without the `content_type_id` and `content_type` so I get this error

**Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined**

This is a jsFiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/9x426Lv7/2/

How can I skip this element in the find method? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, an array of objects

Comment: Store the result of `.find()` and test it before you try to access the `contentType` property

Comment: Does `contentTypes.filter(e => e !== undefined).find(...)` work for you?

Comment: So test if it exists before you use it. Find the object in the array, do not try to use the properties. Check if it exists, if it does, read the props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koala7, you can try this

```
const setType = (selectedType) => {
    _setType(selectedType)
    let typeString = contentTypes.find((item) => {
        return item.contentType.content_type_id === selectedType
    })
    typeString = typeString ? typeString.contentType.content_type : null; // null or give it another default value
    onTypeChange(typeString)
}
```

Comment: you need change const for let if you don't want to add a second variable. else use 2 const

Answer (score 0):

apparently your find function is not getting any value and returning undefined, check if the selected type you are trying to find really exists

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
const setType = (selectedType) => {
    const typeString = contentTypes.find((item) => {
        return item.contentType.content_type_id === selectedType
    })
    if(typeString) {
     return contentType.content_type;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think @Koala7 doesn't want to `return` the value but pass it to the onTypeChange function